# How to load a notebook from the filesystem in JupyterLite without the upload option

Tags: jupyterlite

I'm trying to load a notebook I have in my filesystem using the menu `File` -> `Open from path`.

I have tried to put the notebook in several paths, inside the folder JupyterLite runs from, and to write those paths as absolute, relative to the JupyterLite folder, and relative to the `lab` folder.

I always get the error `Cannot open. Could not find path: <path>`

I'm starting to wonder if I have just misread something and the only way you can open a notebook from JupyterLite is the upload button.

Sorry if this is a very silly question, and thanks for the help!

---

Sorry, I oversimplified the question.

I set up a JupyterLite instance in my computer following [these](https://jupyterlite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart/standalone.html) instructions.

After I run it with `jupyter lite serve` I can access it in `http://localhost:8000/lab/index.html`.

I thought I would be able to access notebooks inside the folder I passed as `--output-dir`, but I can't.

I guess I need to do something else for those notebooks to be available to JupyterLite. Probably I've just misread the docs, but I've been stuck a while with this.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: It is definitely not a silly question at all. However, I'm having trouble understanding specifically what you mean by "inside the folder JupyterLite runs from"?  Especially in light of the statement "a notebook I have in my filesystem" and, perhaps most importantly, **that you don't tell us where you are access JupyterLite or running it from where**? Presumably that phrase  "a notebook I have in my filesystem" refers to a local file system or is that on **and in** the same server system as JupyterLite is being served from? ...

Comment: <continued>  Maybe a better way to get at this would be to ask if you followed [here](https://github.com/jupyterlite/demo?tab=readme-ov-file) to set up your own JupyterLite system and put the notebook you are trying to load in the 'content' directory of your repo? And another way to prompt for more information about what you are doing and how to accomplish what your title says is let me tell you how I usually use JupyterLite typically and how I would do something along the lines of what you ask in your title. So to use JupyterLite I typically go to ...

Comment: <continued>  [the main JupyterLite page](https://jupyterlite.readthedocs.io/en/stable/) and press on the 'JupyterLab' link in the upper right side next to 'Open demo in a new tab'. Or click the 'JupyterLab' tile at [Try Jupyter](https://jupyter.org/try). For either the content is then served from a Jupyter community served resource and the actual work to run the Python computations runs in my locally-installed web browser occurs via Web Assembly inside my browser. It looks like it has a file browser system in it but that is then at that point in a virtual system only running embedded in ...

Comment: <continued> my browser. I like to think of it as a 'remote system' even though it is really only existing in my local machine. It's 'remote' in the sense that I have no alternative access to the file system it uses because it it is in my browser internals and I can only access that via the JupyterLite GUI. Importantly, that virtual file system cannot see my local files because of web security concerns and sandboxing of web assembly computations. (At least that is my understanding of roughly how things work at present.) So there I have to upload my additional files to get them to show up ...

Comment: <continued> in the virtual system that JupyterLite presents to me. However, if I set up my own repo using [this a fork of this repo as a basis](https://github.com/jupyterlite/demo?tab=readme-ov-file) and following [the guide referenced at the repo](https://jupyterlite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart/deploy.html), in my fork I could put Jupyter `ipynb` files from my local computer system into that '`content`' sub-directory of my fork and then after committing them I can go open my JupyterLite deployment and it will have my `.ipynb` files avilable. Adding and updating further is along ...

Comment: <continued> those lines and is covered under ['Contents' here](https://jupyterlite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart/deploy.html#contents).

Comment: Sorry, I had missed that you had updated the original post in response to my comments. You reference the instructions there and they start off saying it will be an empty site, and then it has a section under it 'Customizing the site', at https://jupyterlite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/quickstart/standalone.html#customizing-the-site . If you follow the link for 'Adding content' you get more information at https://jupyterlite.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howto/content/files.html . Be sure to read: "When a user changes a server-hosted file, a copy will be made to the browser’s storage, ...

Comment: <continued> usually in IndexedDB. A user’s locally-modified copy will take precedence over any server contents, even if the server contents are newer." So you say "I thought I would be able to access notebooks inside the folder I passed as --output-dir, but I can't." Using what I indicate in my prevous content you should be able to put content to start out with in your built site. But once it is built you cannot swap stuff in from actual directory, I don't think. Because it is built and using the files that now exist in the virtual system in the browser. The virtual system and the ...

Comment: <continued> file system actually on your machine have no connection once the JupyterLite site is built. Does that help at all?